# Using style bind to set scss variables

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I have a Vue component which I am wanting to style using properties passed in to it.

Ultimately I am wanting to set my global scss variables dependent on a color passed in to the component.

I have created a simplified version of what I am trying to do but the `:style` is not setting the variable how I hope.

Is this possible to do / how should I do this?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p :style="{ $backgroundColor: 'green' }">{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  $backgroundColor: red;

  p {
    background: $backgroundColor;
  }

</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/335379/

Comment: Instead of adding an inline style you should consider using a css class, and changing it instead of the inline style.

Comment: @Adriano I've been trying something like that but can't figure out a way to change the variables: https://jsfiddle.net/801nd1vy/2/

Comment: not possible. SCSS is for the Sass compiler to read. You cannot  pass value from template/Javascript from Vue to the Sass compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
$backgroundColor: red !default;
p {
  $backgroundColor: green; // you can set any color here
  background: $backgroundColor;
}
```

updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/335387/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it doesn't work. The variable is set just for that p tag which goes against the reason of having a global variable. 
I have demonstrated in the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/335389/